# Which ML algorithm is suitable for a dataset that has seasonality and trend?

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, lstm, prophet

I have a small dataset from 2006 to 2023, I would like to predict monthly sales for the next year. This is my data:

[image]

I already tried Prophet and NeuralProphet, but unfortunately they don't work well after many trials with different parameters, I am doing my internship, so I don't have so much experience in this field, it would be great if experts give me some recommendation which algorithms can give me better results ? I was thinking about LSTM, but I think it needs many sample data for training. I am using python for programming.

Comment: You can start even more basic with an autocorrelation and then [autoregression](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/autoregressions.html) models, especially if you have a smaller dataset before jumping to LSTMs.

Comment: Just found an even better comparison between [ARIMA, Prophet, and LSTM](https://neptune.ai/blog/arima-vs-prophet-vs-lstm)

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago a blog post criticizing Prophet became very popular: https://www.microprediction.com/blog/prophet. One of the Prophet authors commented on the issue, basically agreeing with the post in [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/seanjtaylor/status/1410447403153457152?s=21)

The author of the post talks a lot about time series forecasting on his blog (https://www.microprediction.com/blog), and maintains a ranking with comparisons between different approaches (https://www.microprediction.com/ blog/fast). I think you can get ideas from there.

In general, Python people seem to tend to use [pmdarima](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima) or other packages that have an auto-ARIMA implementation, while R people tend to use [auto.arima](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.21.1/topics/auto.arima) from the forecast package.